# Google Maps v3 custom map marker icon but with infowindow content from google

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've been wondering about this for some time:

Is it possible to let a custom marker for a place on a google map display an infowindow with the same information that the infowindows on maps.google.com display when clicking on a place, without having to generate the HTML for the content yourself (using the places library)? I hope you know what I mean. Please let me know if I'm being unclear.

It would be great if one could pull the information straight from google instead of having to do it manually. I mean, why do something that's already there, right? ;)

Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

edit: I've tried rephrasing my question to make it clearer. I've removed the example code because it was just adding to the confusion. Sorry, English isn't my first language ...

Comment: If google already generates an info window, why would you want to duplicate something that exists and works? Looks like the XY Problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858

Comment: I'm talking about a custom map, with custom markers and whatnot. To place the custom marker I've used google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng). AFAIK a map like that doesn't automagically create infowindows like the Google Maps website does when searching for an address. Unless I'm missing something ... I've updated my intial post with a code snippet.

Comment: So when a custom marker is clicked, you want an info window to display with the information that would normally be displayed if the user clicked on that location on a map without the marker?

Comment: almost, I want to display the information that google display on their own maps site when you click on a marker. For instance when you click a marker for a business or something like that. As an example, click on the following link and then on marker A. Link: [google maps](http://g.co/maps/ehh5v) ... I want that information to display on a custom marker, without having to do it manually.

Comment: That's what the places library is for: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

Comment: I know about the places library, but is there no way of letting google decide which information it displays in the infowindow? Or do you have to do this manually when using a custom map? I wish I was able to explain myself clearer :)

Comment: I think the closest you can get to "letting google decide" what to show, is to just take the first search result for each marker's lat/lng (or whatever you're searching Places API with). The API ranks them by relevance.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Does that mean you'd still have to pull out all the information from the returned search result manually? Like the street address, town, website and button for planing a route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API call from Google that will provide the default InfoWindow content for a Lat/Long location.

The only thing google currently provides is some [Reverse Geocoding Infomation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).